# How to get the same value in a Json/array as the user input?

Tags: json, angular, pipe, ngfor

I want to search through a Json and get the same value as the user input.
I don't know why my code is not working. So e.g. the user search for car. If car is in the Json. It should show in the page the word car.
 Here is my code:

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
if(!items) return [];
if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {
        return it.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
});
```

}
}

Html:

```
      <li *ngFor="let char of characters | filter : searchText" > 
          {{ searchText}}  
          {{char.name}}
          {{char.age}}
      </li>

</ul>
```

Component:

```
export class SearchComponent  {
characters: any[] = [
      {
        "name": "audi",
        "age": 1999
      },
      {
        "name": "toyota",
       "age": 2000
      }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your pipe should be like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
 name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
if(!items) return [];
if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {
    return it.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it still not working. I think the problem is in the html file. I can't compare the values in  'character.name'  with the input value. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: How do you input the search text value?  is it using a template reference variable?

Comment: I fixed it with your help! In the component I remove " :any[] " and it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it.toString() returns something like: [object Object]

Try JSON.stringify(it).toLowerCase().includes(searchText);